# Css depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

I try to change the CSS according to the size of the screen, I tried with a simple example to understand the principle except that it did not work for me, here is my code.

```css
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
       p{
       color: red;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <head>
     <title>Css depending on screen size</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>This is a test paragraphe</p>
    </body>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is a very broad question, and it doesn't look like your CSS is wrong. Have you tried one of the great online tutorials, such as [this MDN one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: your example works pretty fine (at least for me)

Comment: When I change screen size i expect text color to be red, but nothing happens.

Comment: look [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/12d9pqw3/) everything works

Comment: its working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work rule @media add section `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: only this will not enough he need media queries knowledge also and how to use them effectively

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem